# ¿Porque debo referenciar al principio de un archivo .ts?

Tags: typescript

Estoy trabajando con TypeScript, namespace mas específicamente, La duda surge al incluir una referencia a un archivo de los namespace (Clientes, Empleados) en la linea 468 y 469 pero me da error.

[image: Referencia]

[image: namespace Empleado]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El error que me aparece en consola es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se puede leer una propiedad que esta indefinida.

Pero cuando introduzco esta misma referencia en la linea 1 del archivo el error se va y me muestra el mensaje al que estoy accediendo.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Porque se debe esto? se que el archivo se lee de arriba hacia abajo, pero habrá una prioridad de lectura? lee las referencias primero y luego lo demás o como funciona? alguien que me ayude.

Es de curioso quiero saber el porque, he buscado en Google pero no encuentro una respuesta, Gracias

Comment: Hola Isaac, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina las imágenes, y agrega tu código y mensajes de error como texto, así evitarás recibir votos negativos, gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esas referencias se llaman [Triple-Slash Directives](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/triple-slash-directives.html)

Y la documentación indica:

> Triple-slash directives are single-line comments containing a single
> XML tag. The contents of the comment are used as compiler directives.
>
> **Triple-slash directives are only valid at the top of their containing**
> **file**. A triple-slash directive can only be preceded by single or
> multi-line comments, including other triple-slash directives. If they
> are encountered following a statement or a declaration they are
> treated as regular single-line comments, and hold no special meaning.

Lo que está en negritas se traduce como

> **Las *Triple-slash directives* solo son válidas en la parte superior del archivo**.